# I am trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to my mySQL database with dis code:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME','pets');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PSW','password');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSW);
if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect to DB ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);if (!db_selected) {
    die('Cant use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected!";
```

But it never displays anything, it's just blank. I have php installed, and this displays info:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I am running PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3

Can You please help me?? Thank You!

Comment: Check your server error log.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running. The mysql extension was removed in PHP 7, you need to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Does `<?php echo "Hello world";` also not show anything? or `<?php echo "Hello world"; define('DB_NAME','pets');...` - Look at your html source; what does it reveal, "code"?

Comment: Where can i check server error log?

Comment: I am running PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3! Then propably this is the problem. Yes?

Comment: ^ that comment (*"I am running PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3"*) just closed the question. The `mysql_` API will not run on php 7, it's been deleted. Use the `mysqli_` or PDO api.

Comment: Yes <?php echo "Hello world"; does print out "Hello world!"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php *"**Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was **removed** in PHP 7.0.0."*

Comment: Can I even upvote theese comments?

Comment: Probably not, TBH I can't remember if low rep members can upvote comments, but you can try ;-)

Comment: However, what would have shown you something, would have been PHP's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php